# Run jQuery and MooTools in jsfiddle simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, jsfiddle

I have some code that uses both jQuery and MooTools. Running it in Expressions Web, I have included the script tags for jQuery and MooTools and started the jQuery part like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
```

The MooTools followed after the jQuery closed. How can I achieve the same in jsfiddle, so that both jQuery and MooTools work simultaneously in the javascript section?

Here is the jsfiddle I am trying to run: http://jsfiddle.net/HamishT/fW8Y7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways to add scripts is jsFiddle. In the "Frameworks & Extensions" and in "External Resources". You can get the link to jQuery or MooTools at: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

So from there you can do a fiddle like: http://jsfiddle.net/fW8Y7/2/

MooTools detects if the `$` is already in use, in case you load MooTools after jQuery. So in that case you could use the `$` for jQuery and `document.id` in MooTools wich is alias for `$`.

Anyway, unsing `.noConflict()` as you did is to me the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *"External Resources"* panel to add additional files. So add either jquery or mootools in the Frameworks panel and then add a url (e.g. cdn url) to the other in the external resources

[image: JSFiddle screenshot]